KEDA with docker desktop and Azure Service bus connection string for Trigger Authentication
I need some help configuring KEDA in my local docker desktop for service bus trigger function. It is all working tested in Azure AKS but I like to setup the same in my local Docker Desktop.
On Azure, I use Azure Managed Workload Identity but in local, I believe that's not possible (Visual Studio Identity not possible in KEDA, I believe)
So, I like to use service bus connection string in trigger authentication.
Here is my file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.trigger.serviceBusNameSpace }}-secret
  namespace: {{ .Values.config.namespace }}
data:
  servicebus-connectionstring: xxxxxx
--- 
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.config.name }}-auth
  namespace: {{ .Values.config.namespace }}
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
  - parameter: connection
    name: {{ .Values.trigger.serviceBusNameSpace }}-secret
    key: servicebus-connectionstring
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.config.name }}-scaledobject
  namespace: {{ .Values.config.namespace }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: {{ .Values.config.name }}-deployment
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 1
triggers:
- type: azure-servicebus
  metadata:
    namespace: {{ .Values.trigger.serviceBusNameSpace }}
    topicName: {{ .Values.trigger.serviceBusTopicName }}
    subscriptionName: {{ .Values.trigger.serviceBusSubscriptionName }}
  authenticationRef:
    name: {{ .Values.config.name }}-auth

Now, after deployment, I am keep getting an following message on POD
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..

I found the issue..
Initially I thought it was KEDA issue and somehow the connectionstring is not working with trigger authentication and may be my configuration is wrong or something is missing. But later (after a few hours of troubleshooting) I found the issue was with the NODE. NODE was not having a label that matches with the deployment. I corrected and that started deploying correctly.
So, basically my above configuration is correct and working.
Thank you and sorry to bother you all.
